# Manejar una lista de items con imagenes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Buen día

Mi consulta es la siguiente me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para moverme por una lista, objeto por objeto mostrándome la información registro por registro. Me explico tengo mi primer actionResult que recibe la información para generar el listado.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(VariablesEntrada datos)
    {

        DateTime fecha = datos.fecha;
        string fechaformateada = fecha.ToString(); 
        short NumProceso = datos.numEntrega;

        return RedirectToAction("Trabajo", new RouteValueDictionary(
              new { controller = "ControlCalidadFir", action = "Trabajo", Id = 0 , fechaProceso = fechaformateada, NumProceso = NumProceso }));// RedirectToAction es para pasar valores entre acciones del mismos controlador
    }
```

Al pasarlo los parámetros de fecha y proceso el va y llena la lista completa.  y luego tomo un objeto de esa lista y se la paso a la vista.

```
   public ActionResult Trabajo(int Id, string fechaProceso, short NumProceso )
    {
        List<ControlCalidadFir> listadoOut = new List<ControlCalidadFir>();
        ConexionBDReplicaSOS Listadoin = new ConexionBDReplicaSOS();
        listadoOut = Listadoin.ConsultaCalidadFIR(fechaProceso, NumProceso);

        foreach (var item in listadoOut)
        {
            //listadofinal = listado;
           int posicion = Id;
           int posicionac = BottonSiguiente(Id);
            if (posicion < 0)
            {
                posicion = 0;
                Id = 0;
            }

            // posicion = 1;
            var numero = listadoOut[posicion];// objeto en la posicion 0
            string nuevaImagen = "convirtio";

            //conviterte tiff a png

            //     Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(numero.Url);
            Bitmap.FromFile(numero.Url)
            .Save(@"C:\Windows\Temp\" + nuevaImagen + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            //cierra
            string imagenpng = @"C:\Windows\Temp\convirtio.png";
            byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagenpng);
            string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteData);
            //    string imageDataURL = string.Format(imageBase64Data);


            ViewBag.ImageData = imageBase64Data;

            //Llama la ayuda de tipos de afiliacion

            cargaCombos();

            ViewBag.contador = posicion;
            return View(numero);
        }

        return View();

    }
```

pero necesito moverme uno por uno de los registros con un boton siguiente y uno atrás, para que el usuario se pueda mover por la lista. El problema que tengo es la posición en la que la lista esta, ya que  ejemplo: si el usuario da siguiente el tiene que ir al siguiente registro, pero no se como pesarle esa posición a la acción ya que si la mando a la misma acción de trabajo me va querer cargar siempre la lista y eso seria muy malo para la base de datos. Ademas como la acción necesita dos parámetros estos se perderán y me generaran un error de null. Entonces necesito mantener la lista llena y moverme por los registros a merced de donde el usuario quiera ir.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partamos de la base que este tipo de diseño no lo recomendaria, estas diseñando al estilo winform cuando estas en web, lo cual es pesimo. Lo correcto es que listas al usuario los resultados en un grid y este seleccion que entidad quiere editar, es mas podrias proporcionar filtros sobre la lista y paginado si son muchos los items.

En tu caso haya varias formas de conservar la posicion para poder desplazarte al seleccionar next

- Podrias asignar esta al objeto Session, con lo cual el dato quedaria en el servidor, la proxima accion tomarias ese valor y devolverias la siguiente entidad
- Si asignas la posicion en el ViewBag y la usas en el Html.Hidden() de esta forma cuando se realice en siguiente post tomarias el valor como parametro del action.

Entiendo que en tu caso seria el `ViewBag.contador` lo que deberias asignar al hidden pero esta algo raro, porque despues nunca lo recibes en el proximo post, deberias asignarlo al hidden para tenerlo en el action y conseguir el siguiente

```
@Html.Hidden("Id", ViewBag.contador)
```

Comment: Me gusta tu idea del grid pero he buscado y no encuentro como hacer un grid en web donde podría encontrar como utilizarlo gracias.